# How do I emit the data asynchronously from server to client in socket.io

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, socket.io

Here I'm emitting the data from app.js to index.html page.But I'm not getting the asynchronous data.

Here I'm trying to download a file and try to send the download progress to the index.html.But in "index.html",I'm getting the data once the download is complete.I don't want this to happen.

If the file is downloaded 40% then the same should display in the browser also.How can I achieve this? Can anyone please help me out ...

My app.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var progress = require('request-progress');

var DOWNLOAD_DIR = '/usr/local/';
var file_name = 'jquery.js' 

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express ();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);



http.listen(8085, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:8085');
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

app.get('/get', function (req, res) {
progress(request('https://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js'), {
    throttle:0,   
    delay: 0       
})
.on('progress', function(state){
    console.log('received size in bytes', state.received);
    console.log('total size in bytes', state.total);
    console.log('percent', state.percent);
io.of('/socket_issue').on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("Socket connected :"+socket.id);
 socket.emit('message', JSON.stringify({size: state.total, received: state.received, percent: state.percent, fileName: file_name}));
});


})

.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(DOWNLOAD_DIR + file_name))
.on('error', function (err) {
 console.log("error");  
})
.on('close', function (err){
console.log("Download Complete"); 
});

 res.sendfile('views/index.html');

});




// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

My index.html :

```
<html>

<body>
<script src="http://localhost:8085/javascripts/socket.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8085/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8085/javascripts/bootstrap-progressbar.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8085/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" />

    <div id="progressbar"><div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = io('http://localhost:8085/socket_issue');
  socket.on('connect', function(){ console.log('connected to socket'); });
  socket.on('error', function(e){ console.log('error' + e); });
  socket.on('message', function(data){
   console.log(data);


       function progress(percent, $element) {
        var progressBarWidth = percent * $element.width() / 100;
        $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500).html(percent + "% ");
    }
    progress(JSON.parse(data).percent, $('#progressbar'));

  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In index.html (edited)

```
<body onload="timedRefresh(10000);">

<script type="text/javaScript">
    function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
     setTimeout("window.location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're downloading a 200kb file on the server...your client has far more to load. jquery-ui alone, for example, is over 400 kilobytes. So the server is probably done downloading the file before the client even has the opportunity to connect and listen for download progress.

As a side note, I'd recommend you move `io.of('socket_issue').on...` outside of the `.on('progress'` event. It doesn't make sense to start listening for socket.io connections every time someone requests `/get`

Comment: So,How can we solve this isuue ... can you please edit the code,I'm really stucked over here

Comment: download a bigger file?

Comment: k I'll try on downloading a bigger file

Comment: I have downloaded a .tar.gz file .I'm getting the asynchronous data.But the problem is ,I need to refresh the html continuously.

Comment: so you're getting the data in your console but it's not animating?

Comment: yes.I had kept the edited code.I want the html page to refresh until the download is done.After the download is complete,Idon't want to refresh the page.How can I achieve this ?